# List categories and exclude child categories

Tags: theme-development

The script below creates a listing of the categories in the site (excluding those in "uncategorized").

If possible, I'd like to modify it so that it only lists the top level categories (no child categories)...

```
    $cat_args = array('orderby' => 'name', 'show_count' => $c, 'hierarchical' => $h);
    $cat_args['title_li'] = '';
    $cat_args['exclude_tree'] = 1;
    wp_list_categories(apply_filters('widget_categories_args', $cat_args));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trial and error, this is what it took to make it work...

```
    $cat_args = array('orderby' => 'count');
    $cat_args['title_li'] = '';
    $cat_args['exclude_tree'] = 1;
    $cat_args['exclude'] = 1;
    $cat_args['depth'] = 1;
    wp_list_categories(apply_filters('widget_categories_args', $cat_args));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$cat_args = array('orderby' => 'name', 'show_count' => $c, 'hierarchical' => $h);
$cat_args['title_li'] = '';
$cat_args['exclude_tree'] = 1;
$cat_args['depth'] = 1;
wp_list_categories(apply_filters('widget_categories_args', $cat_args));
```

I added the 'depth' argument to your array. Check out the [Codex Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) for full documentation of the function.

Comment: Thanks Phil, that didn't work for me (in WP 3.0.1, it lists everything, including children). I was only able to get it to work using the answer I just provided.